# Laravel 4 validation constant pass

Tags: php, forms, validation, laravel, laravel-4

I'm using Laravel 4.2.8 and trying to validate the next form:
[image: Form]

The first select field is required. And only one is required from the next three fields.
Phone with formatting is the last. And another two are for digits (some IDs).
I validate in controller, the code is next:

```
public function getApplication()
{
    $input = Input::except('_token');
    Debugbar::info($input);
    $input['phone'] = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $input['phone']); // remove format from phone
    $input = array_map('intval', $input); // convert all numeric data to int
    Debugbar::info($input);

    $rules = [ // Validation rules
        ['operation-location' => 'required|numeric'],
        ['app-id' => 'numeric|min:1|required_without_all:card-id,phone'],
        ['card-id' => 'numeric|digits:16|required_without_all:app-id,phone'],
        ['phone' => 'numeric|digits:12|required_without_all:app-id,card-id']
    ];

    $validator = Validator::make($input, $rules);
    if ($validator->passes()) {
        Debugbar::info('Validation OK');

        return Redirect::route('appl.journal', ['by' => 'application']);
    }
    else { // Validation FAIL
        Debugbar::info('Validation error');
        // Redirect to form with error
        return Redirect::route('appl.journal', ['by' => 'application'])
            ->withErrors($validator)
            ->withInput();
    }
}
```

As you may see I convert numeric IDs to integers myself and leave only number for phone number.
The problem is when I submit form as it is, it passes validation, despite one field is required and starter phone format is too short.
I've tried changing required_without_all to just required on all fields (!), but it still passes fine with blank empty form submitted.
And I expect at least one field to be properly filled.

Debug of my inputs.
Initial:

```
    array(4) [
    'operation-location' => string (1) "0"
    'app-id' => string (0) ""
    'card-id' => string (0) ""
    'phone' => string (6) "+3 8(0"
]
```

After conversion to int:

```
    array(4) [
    'operation-location' => integer 0
    'app-id' => integer 0
    'card-id' => integer 0
    'phone' => integer 380
]
```

Posted similar smaller problem to  [Laravel issues](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/5467).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know this sounds weird but I think this is just an issue with your rules array.

You current rules array is an array of arrays. The Validator looks for an array with keys and values. I believe your current rules are being parsed as keys, but with no value. And then the Validator was basically seeing no rules, and it automatically passed. Try this.

```
$rules = [
    'operation-location' => 'required|numeric',
    'app-id' => 'numeric|min:1|required_without_all:card-id,phone',
    'card-id' => 'numeric|digits:16|required_without_all:app-id,phone',
    'phone' => 'numeric|digits:12|required_without_all:app-id,card-id'
];
```

Comment: Thank you so much! How could I miss this.

Comment: No problem, man. We all make those silly mistakes at one time or another.